# Getting error in ejabberd when add any module in ODBC mod

Tags: mysql, erlang, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd to implement my chat application, I have also successfully installed Mysql module and using mysql database in place of mnesia(default of ejabberd).Everything is working fine,Now i am trying to some module for ODBC mod, like mod_muc to mod_muc_odbc, then i am getting error like,

```
 =ERROR REPORT==== 2014-01-20 11:39:08 ===
C(<0.37.0>:gen_mod:75) : Problem starting the module mod_muc_odbc for host "localhost" 
 options: [{host,"conference.@HOST@"},
           {access,muc},
           {access_create,muc},
           {access_persistent,muc},
           {access_admin,muc_admin},
           {max_users,500}]
 error: undef

=ERROR REPORT==== 2014-01-20 11:39:08 ===
C(<0.37.0>:gen_mod:80) : ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

How to fix it ? Another question related with ejabberd is that , Can i see the whole chat record in mysql database, if yes then how ?

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using?

Comment: I am using ejabberd 2.1.10.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. Just another module. This part of log:

```
{max_users,500}]
 error: undef
```

means that you ejabbered  was not compiled with that specific module support.

I am using gentoo linux so it was easy to me to add USE="mymodule" emerge -av ejabered and compile ejjabered with mymodule that was missing.

In your post I can not see what linux distro are you using? But you get a picture from my answer.